# modificar recycleview desde spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

estoy tratando de crear un recyclerview que dependiendo de la opción que tenga el spinner cargue una lista u otra, pero no logro hacerlo... este es mi código

```
 /*variables*/
Spinner comboFiltro;
private List<ControlHorario> elements;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ListAdapterCtrl listAdapter;
AccesoBD bd;
String sql= "SELECT idControl, valor, Hora, fecha, h.Horario, Dosis, Comentarios, idUsuario " +
        "FROM Controles c JOIN Horarios h ON c.idHorario= h.idHorarios " +
        "WHERE date(fecha) >= date('now', '-30 days') " +
        "ORDER BY date(fecha) DESC, time(hora) DESC";
TextView mensaje;

public ControlListaPrueba() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_controles_lista, container, false);
    bd = AccesoBD.getInstance(getContext());
    elements = getListItemsMensual();
    recyclerView = vista.findViewById(R.id.idListaSemanalControles);
    mensaje= vista.findViewById(R.id.txtMensajeControl);

    /*Carga del spinner*/
    
    comboFiltro = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spnFechasDias);
    ArrayList<String> catCombo= new ArrayList<>();
    catCombo.add("Ultimo mes");
    catCombo.add("Ultimos 15 dias");
    catCombo.add("Ultima semana");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item_glicodex, catCombo );
    comboFiltro.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    /* el selected listener*/
    comboFiltro.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(position == 0)
            {
                elements = getListItemsMensual();
            }
            else
            {
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    elements = getListItemsQuincenal();
                }
                else
                {
                    elements = getListItemsQuincenal();
                }
            }
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            InitViews();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    InitViews();
    InitValues();

    return vista;
}


/*Layout manager*/
public void InitValues()
{
    LinearLayoutManager manager;
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
}

/*Vistas*/
private void InitViews()
{
    //titulo.setText("Ultimos 7 dias: ");

    if (elements == null)
    {
        mensaje.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        listAdapter = new ListAdapterCtrl(elements);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

}


/*Las listas que quiero cambiar*/
private List<ControlHorario> getListItemsMensual()
{
    List<ControlHorario> items = bd.getControles("SELECT idControl, valor, Hora, fecha, h.Horario, Dosis, Comentarios, idUsuario " +
            "FROM Controles c JOIN Horarios h ON c.idHorario= h.idHorarios " +
            "WHERE date(fecha) >= date('now', '-7 days') " +
            "ORDER BY date(fecha) DESC, time(hora) DESC;");

    return items;
}
private List<ControlHorario> getListItemsQuincenal()
{
    List<ControlHorario> items = bd.getControles("SELECT idControl, valor, Hora, fecha, h.Horario, Dosis, Comentarios, idUsuario " +
            "FROM Controles c JOIN Horarios h ON c.idHorario= h.idHorarios " +
            "WHERE date(fecha) >= date('now', '-15 days') " +
            "ORDER BY date(fecha) DESC, time(Hora) DESC;");

    return items;
}
private List<ControlHorario> getListItemsSemanal()
{
    List<ControlHorario> items = bd.getControles("SELECT idControl, valor, Hora, fecha, h.Horario, Dosis, Comentarios, idUsuario " +
            "FROM Controles c JOIN Horarios h ON c.idHorario= h.idHorarios " +
            "WHERE date(fecha) >= date('now', '-7 days') " +
            "ORDER BY date(fecha) DESC, time(hora) DESC;");

    return items;
}
```

Si alguien sabe como hacerlo o tiene un tuto que pueda ver se lo agradecería... no hay forma de que cambie la lista, vi que con el notifyDataSetChanged() debería funcionar, pero por mas de que cambie de opción las listas no se actualizan ni nada. si alguien sabe como puedo hacer.

[image: Esta es la pantalla con las 3 opciones]

Alguna sugerencia de que puedo cambiar o como puedo lograr cambiar los datos del recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general, se deben limpiar las listas cada vez que realizas una búsqueda, de lo contrario si aparecerán pero con problemas. Bueno, esta es una posible solución, me comentas que tal:

```
comboFiltro.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if(position == 0){
            elements.clear();
            elements = getListItemsMensual();
        }
        else if (position == 1){
            elements.clear();
            elements = getListItemsQuincenal();
        }else{
            elements.clear();
            elements = getListItemsSemanal();
        }
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        InitViews();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Perfecto! Voy a probar eso... Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Es casí correcto como lo realizas pero es importante inicializar el `Adapter` con la nueva lista ya sea enviando la información en un método del Adapter que los actualice o creando una nueva instancia con la nueva lista.

```
 comboFiltro.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(position == 0)
            {
                elements = getListItemsMensual();
            }
            else
            {
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    elements = getListItemsQuincenal();
                }
                else
                {
                    elements = getListItemsQuincenal();
                }
            }

            //Inicializa Adapter con nuevos datos.            
            listAdapter = new ListAdapterCtrl(elements);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            InitViews();

        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Voy a hacer ese cambio y anprobar michss gracias